# Turning a simple json array to a csv string using PostgreSQL

Tags: string, postgresql, data-manipulation

I tried looking in the already open questions but nothing helped me unfortunately.
I'm trying to convert a json array to a string separated by commas, using the jsonb_array_elements and the string_agg function, but I keep getting the same error no matter how I try - "ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar"

Let's assume that my JSON data looks like: `{ "id" : "hi", "list" : ["a", "b", "c"] }`.

What I'm trying to get is a query that results in a row that looks like : `[id, list participants] = [hi, a,b,c]`

I tried some different methods but the most recent one was:

```
select (select string_agg(t->>0, ',') from jsonb_array_elements(data->'list') as t) from my_table
```

Would really appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of attempts with many different methods - every method attempted has resulted in the same "ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar".

I eventually figured out that the query was not the problem, instead it was the data!
If one of the lists in the data is empty( "{[]}" ) it would result in that error. So after excluding those empty lists from the query using a WHERE clause, I finally got it working! Thanks, hopefully this post will help future frustrated query users :)

For reference, the method I eventually chose is:

```
SELECT t.tbl, d.list
FROM tbl t, LATERAL (
     SELECT string_agg(value::text, ', ') AS list
     FROM json_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags')
) d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for example

```
with c as (
select 1,'{ "id" : "hi", "list" : ["a", "b", "c"] }'::jsonb->>'id' as value 
union 
select 2,string_agg(t->>0, ',') from jsonb_array_elements('{ "id" : "hi", "list" : ["a", "b", "c"] }'::jsonb->'list') as t
)
select string_agg(c.value,',') from c order by 1
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! just a question,
Wouldn't I get the same error using the select 2 command? as it's the same method I was trying to use for my case?